# Attach runtime event to dynamic elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, dynamic, runtime, element

I have created a small example on jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/0rve9cwf/

In short, when I create an element dynamically and add a click handler, it is assigning the *result* of the called function to the new element, rather than calling the attached function during runtime, which is not the behavior I expected or wanted.  Then, when you actually click the button, nothing happens.  What is the best practice to attach a function to a dynamically created object which should be executed at *runtime*?

**HTML**

```
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>Binding event handler dynamically</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function result(val1, val2) {
    console.log(`val1:  ${val1}, val2:  ${val2}`);
}

let btn         = document.createElement('button');
btn.textContent = 'Click me';
btn.addEventListener('click', result(
    'first value',
    'second value'
));

let body        = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0];
body.append(btn);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to add a `() =>` . You need to pass a function as a second parameter to `addEventListener`, and in your case your function is executed immediately.

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => result(
  'first value',
  'second value'
));
```

Answer (score 1):

i hope this solves the problem

```js
function result(val1, val2) {
    console.log(`val1:  ${val1}, val2:  ${val2}`);
}

let btn        = document.createElement('button');
btn.textContent = 'Click me';
btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {result(
    'first value',
  'second value'
)});

let body        = document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0];
body.appendChild(btn);
```

```html
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>Binding event handler dynamically</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    </body>
</html>
```